# How can I resize me project on Memgraph Cloud?

Tags: memgraphdb

How can I make my instance deployed on Memgraph Cloud larger? I didn't expect that I'll need to ingest so much data from connected IoT sensors. Now I need to increase the memory size since I'm afraid that I'll reach the limit pretty soon.

Comment: Kill or delete that instance, then reconfigure and submit a fresh one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an answer in the Memgraph Cloud documentation:
https://memgraph.com/docs/getting-started/install-memgraph/memgraph-cloud#resize-a-project

When your project becomes to big for the current compute, upgrade it:

1. [Back up the project](https://memgraph.com/docs/getting-started/install-memgraph/memgraph-cloud#back-up-a-project) by creating a snapshot.
2. [Clone the project](https://memgraph.com/docs/getting-started/install-memgraph/memgraph-cloud#restore-or-clone-a-project) to a bigger project.
3. [Delete the smaller project.](https://memgraph.com/docs/getting-started/install-memgraph/memgraph-cloud#pause-resume-or-delete-a-project)